# inverse image presheaf of the inclusion of a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a presheaf over a topological space $Y$. If $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous map, then we have a natural presheaf on $X$ given by
$$f^{-1}\mathscr{F}(U):= \operatorname{colim}_{f(U)\subset V}\mathscr{F}(V).$$
(Most people will say that the inverse image is the sheafification of that but it'll be enough to consider this for now.)

If $f:\{p\}\to X$ is the inclusion of a point and $\mathscr{G}$ is a presheaf on $X$, I want to calculate the presheaf $f^{-1}\mathscr{G}$. The topological space $\{p\}$ has only two open sets. By definition, $\Gamma(\{p\},f^{-1}\mathscr{G})$ is the stalk $\mathscr{G}_p$. Now, I wonder what is $\Gamma(\varnothing,f^{-1}\mathscr{G})$.

It surely is the colimit of $\mathscr{G}(V)$ where $V$ runs over all the open sets of $X$ but I can't say nothing more precise. Does this object has a better description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, it's the colimit of $\mathscr G(V)$ where $V$ runs over all the open sets. The partially ordered set of the open sets of $V$ has a minimum, which is $\varnothing$. This makes the colimit very easy to compute, namely it's $\mathscr G( \varnothing)$.

Let us check the universal property. Suppose that for some $A$ we have compatible maps $\mathscr G(V)\to A$ for every $V$. Then in particular we have a unique map $\mathscr G(\varnothing)\to A$ that makes everything commute.

So $\Gamma(\varnothing,f^{-1}\mathscr G) = \Gamma(\varnothing,\mathscr G)$. If you have said that $\mathscr G$ is a sheaf, then $\mathscr G(\varnothing)$ is the final object (i.e. $\{*\}$ is we're talking about sheaves of sets or the trivial group if it's sheaves of groups). I'm not sure if this is a convention or it follows from the definition (it seems that it follows from the definition... see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/006U ).